# How to access the value of an object from the previous function evaluation?

Tags: python

I have a function `step()` which alters the value of an object `foo`. `step` is called from another file iteratively to run on different inputs. I want to access the value of `foo` from the last iteration so that I can perform some operation on it in the current iteration. How can I achieve this?

```
def step(blob):
    (some code which accesses foo.pos for blob1)
    foo.pos = op(blob)

def calling_func():
    items = [blob1, blob2, blob3]
    for i in items:
        step(i)
```

So when I pass `blob2` to `step()`, I want to access the value of the attribute `pos` within `step` when `blob1` was passed. And I want to do this as many times as `step` is called. Also, the function `step()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another parameter to `step` and use it as a stack to keep track of the previous values:

```
def step (blob, stack):
    stack.append (foo.pos)
    (some code which accesses foo.pos for blob1)
    foo.pos = op(blob)
    return stack

def calling_func():
    stack = []
    items = [blob1, blob2, blob3]
    for i in items:
        stack = step(i,stack)
```

The list `stack` will always have the last added element at the end, thus `stack.pop()` will give you the element from the last iteration.